# Laravel: Edit file in the vendor directory

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am working with `laravel` and I have installed a package using composer by running this command `composer require mailchimp/mailchimp=~2.0`.

After that I got a folder 'mailchimp' in the vendor directory. In there, there is a file named `Mailchimp.php` that I have to modify, but based on some old posts here, if I modify the file, any time I run the command `composer update`, I will loose my changes in the file, just because it is located in the `vendor` directory. So is there any option for me to solve this problem ?

I tried using the command `php artisan vendor:publish` but I do not get the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom class which will extend the `Mailchimp` class and override the function you want. Then use the custom class in your code.

```
use DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;

class CustomMailChimp extends MailChimp {
    ...
    // The function you would like to override
}
```

Then use it `new CustomMailChimp(..)`